# Getting file information while loading on page with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have upload form where I'm able to upload any type of files and save their path to database. Without saving any relevant information in database such as: `filetype`, `filesize` etc can I get this information while I loop the results and showing them on page?

Here is what I tried so far

```
public function fileUpload()
{
    $allFiles = Documents::paginate(20);

    $files = array();

    foreach ($allFiles as $file) {

        $files[] = $this->fileInfo(pathinfo(public_path() . '/uploads/' . $file));
    }

    return View::make('admin.files', [
        'files' => $files
    ]);
}

public function fileInfo($filePath)
{
    $file = array();
    $file['name'] = $filePath['filename'];
    $file['extension'] = $filePath['extension'];
    $file['size'] = filesize($filePath['dirname'] . '/' . $filePath['basename']);

    return $file;
}
```

The error which I get when I run the page is

> ErrorException: filesize(): stat failed for .....

Is this the correct way of doing this?

Update: `dd($filePath['dirname'] . '/' . $filePath['basename']);` return

```
string(126) "/var/www/html/site/public/uploads/{"id":2,"document_path":"aut6MnADFrPZTz4TJf0Y.pdf","document_name":"Some title for the file"}"
```

Comment: What is the output of `$filePath['dirname'] . '/' . $filePath['basename']`? I see another `$filePath['extension']` and a `$filePath['filename']`, i guess these should be included in the path?

Comment: I can't even `dd` anything. Only this error appear

Comment: Not even before `$file = array();`? Otherwise, try `dd()` with the filestat line commented out.

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
$files[] = $this->fileInfo(pathinfo(public_path() . '/uploads/' . $file));
```

to

```
$files[] = $this->fileInfo(pathinfo(public_path() . '/uploads/' . $file->document_path));
```

Comment: Now the path seem correct `string(58) "/var/www/html/site/public/uploads/aut6MnADFrPZTz4TJf0Y.pdf"` but still the error appear `filesize(): stat failed for `

Comment: just `dd($filePath['dirname'] . '/' . $filePath['basename'])` and see if it is the correct path

Comment: Yes, the path is correct `string(58) "/var/www/html/site/public/uploads/aut6MnADFrPZTz4TJf0Y.pdf"`